# Disable syslog logging for auditd

Tags: linux, logs, syslog, linux-audit

auditd sending logs to `/var/logs/messages` we want to disable it. How to do that?

/etc/audisp/plugins.d/syslog.conf

i changee `active = no` but still sending lots to syslog

Comment: You can place filters in syslog at the worst situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit `/etc/audisp/plugins.d` and change `args = LOG_INFO`to this: `args =  local6`

Then edit `/etc/rsyslog.conf` and add `local6` to the "some catch-all log files" block so it's like this:

```
*.=info;*.=notice;*.=warn;\
        auth,authpriv.none;\
        cron,daemon.none;\
        mail,news.none;\
        local6.none           -/var/log/messages
```

Also change the line `args =` in `/etc/audisp/plugins.d` to:
`args = LOG_LOCAL6`

This was adapted from [this post](https://access.redhat.com/discussions/650853).